# tmdb returns nothing and sometimes returns value

Tags: javascript, node.js, null, themoviedb-api

I'm trying to get a random movie title from tmdb, the code is working but there's a frustrating problem, some random numbers return [absolutely nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/corTi.png), how can I loop or do something or try random numbers till i get a result? I guess there are gaps in tmdb movies id numbers!

```js
const tmdb = require('tmdbv3').init('---');

 function randomMovie(callback){
          var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
          tmdb.movie.info(r, (err ,res) => {
           var x = res.title
           callback(x);
        })};
          
randomMovie(function(title){console.log(title)})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to use this API, because even his test are failing. The problem you face is that if theres a number without data, it doesn't even return its callback, so you cannot handle its error (because it doesn't throw any). This is the best i could get from that API:

```
'use strict';

const tmdb = require('tmdbv3').init('8b39b6f141f42e463b507151122d0971');

function randomMovie(callback) {
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    tmdb.movie.info(r, (err, res) => {
        const x = res.title
        callback(x);
    })
};

function tryTenTimes() {
    let firstTitle;
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        randomMovie(title => {
            if (!firstTitle) {
                firstTitle = title;
                console.log(firstTitle);
            }
        });
    }
}

tryTenTimes();
```

It's an ugly workaround, that does 10 ask, and takes the first valid one.

EDIT: I was asked to do one with a while loop, and this is how I managed to do it

```
'use strict';

const tmdb = require('tmdbv3').init('8b39b6f141f42e463b507151122d0971');

function randomMovie(callback) {
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    tmdb.movie.info(r, (err, res) => {
        const x = res.title
        callback(x);
    })
};
function tryWhileTimes() {
    let firstTitle;
    while (!firstTitle) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            randomMovie(title => {
                if (!firstTitle) {
                    firstTitle = title;
                    console.log(firstTitle);
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

tryWhileTimes()
```

Comment: this code is doing the same thing! is there a better API that can do this task? i searched and seems like this is the only one out there!

Comment: I would suggest not doing a fixed number of calls, instead using a while and stopping just when you get a title,
Also having a max_attempt flag which stops the while

Comment: could you please show me how i can do a while loop in this case?
 @Shivam

Comment: You need to use promises if you want a while loop, I edited with an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the response headers and look at the status code I bet you're getting a 404 (not found) back since the ID has been deleted. And you won't be getting "nothing back" the TMDB API returns a set of errors with codes for you to troubleshoot what is happening. That is documented [here](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api/status-codes).

Depending on what you're doing, knowing what IDs are available in advance will help you. There are some downloadable files for this that you can read about [in the documentation](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/daily-file-exports).